# Troubles with 'bind' and 'function'

Tags: c++, c++11

A while back, I ran into the question of how to pass a callable returned by bind (call it A) to another function (call it B) which expects a parameter which is a pointer to a function of the from A.  I discovered that a callable A returned by bind has a very complicated type and so gave up on my approach.

Then I learned about 'function' in the functional header which sounded as if it would solve my problem.  However, after a few attempts, I was again thwarted!  Perhaps you can help?  Here is some code that will not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>  //Library for "bind" and "function"                                                                                                                                     
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;  //for _1, _2, _3 ...                                                                                                                                       

//praboloid function                                                                                                                                                                           
int parab(int x, int y)  {
  return pow(x,2) + pow(y,2);
}

//Take an integer and a pointer to a function                                                                                                                                                  
int funk(int a, int (*f)(int) )  {
  return (*f)(a);
}

int main()  {
  auto f = bind(parab, _1, 0); // Bind the second value to 0                                                                                                                                  
  function<int (int)> fp = f;

  //Any of the following lines creates and error                                                                                                                                               

  function<int (*)(int)> fp = f; //Error!                                                                                                                                                      
  funk(-5, f);  //Error!                                                                                                                                                                       
  funk(-5, &f); //Error!                                                                                                                                                                       
  funk(-5, fp); //Error!
  funk(-5 &fp); //Error!                                                                                                                                                                   

  return 0;
}
```

All I wish to do is first create a new callable using bind and then send that bound function to another function as a parameter.  If possible, I don't want to have to deal with the messy type returned by bind.

I am open to alternate approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: Drop the `(*f)`. Just `f(a)`, it's cleaner. (You've been doing that all your life. You never write `(*printf)("hello world\n")`, do you.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well technically `printf` names a `function`, and `f` names a `pointer to function`.  As it happens the distinction is blurred by the rule that function calls will accept both, and due to the function-to-pointer standard conversion the indirection form `(*f)(x)` will work for both types too - however it could be argued that using a convension of normal function calls for `functions`, and the indirection form for `pointers to functions`, serves as a hint to the reader as to the named type, and hence where to look for the definition.

Comment: @user1131467 `printf` names a function, but the id-expression `printf` immediately decays to a pointer-to-function. You can also say `(***printf)("hello")`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, the expression `printf` is an lvalue of type `function`.  It only undergoes the function-to-pointer standard conversion if required by the context.  The function call `printf("foo")` is _not_ such a context.  In `(***printf)("hello")` the indirection operator `*` requires a pointer, so the standard conversion _is_ applied in that context, after indirection the expression is a function again, and the process continutes.  `***printf` is again an lvalue of type `function`, that is then used by the function call.  Clear as mud? :)

Comment: @user1131467: Hmm, perhaps :-)

Comment: Thanks for the debate here, but I only did (*f) to be absolutely clear  in the code I posted.  Usually I leave it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `auto f = [](int n) -> int { return parab(n, 0); };`

That should work with `funk(-5, f)` (because non-capturing closures are convertible to function pointers).

`bind` and `function` have their place, but they're not always the best choice.

Comment: Tested and it works like a charm. That `bind` and `function` are not the best tools for this job was the conclusion I was coming to. Thank you for the clean alternate approach!

Answer (score 2):

The type of a `std::function` taking an `int` and returning an `int` is `std::function<int(int)>` not `std::function<int(*)(int)>`.

Second, a `std::function` cannot be converted to a function pointer.  Change the interface of your `funk` to `int funk(int a, std::function<int(int)>)` if you want to pass `std::function`s to it, or make it a `template` argument of unknown type.

Third, if you use a stateless lambda, then that can be passed to a function taking a function pointer.  Stateless lambdas are lambda types that capture  nothing -- that have `[]` nothing in the square brackets.  Your bind expression can be rewritten as a stateless lambda in this case because your binding is a compile time known value.

Comment: First: If you check the code, I used `std::function<int(int)>` but simply observed that `std::function<int(*)(int)>` gives an error. Second: I was hoping to avoid doing what you suggest here although I agree it does "solve" the problem. Third, I believe this is same idea as a previous comment?

Answer (score 2):

`f` is not `int (*f)(int)`. It's functor of unspecified type. But it can be used as a function. So just get any tpe in `funk`

```
template<typename F>
int funk(int a, F f)  {
  return f(a);
}
```

Comment: A template approach... interesting!